# I know [who/to whom] thus job should be entrusted to for smooth handling

Tags: pronouns

> I know who this job should be entrusted to for smooth handling.

Is the *who* pronoun correct here ? It sounds a little weird, I think it should be replaced by *to whom*.

Comment: In traditional grammar, it should be "whom", since it is object of the preposition "to". But like it or lump it, "whom" is disappearing fast, and "who" is becoming dominant. But note that if you fronted the relative word together with the preposition to give the ridiculously formal "I know **to whom** this job should be entrusted for smooth handling", then "who" is not normally allowed.

Answer (score 2):

A few native speakers say that the fine line between using 'who' and 'whom' is getting *vanished*, however, to me it still exists.

For the given example, I'd go for 'whom.'

Ask yourself: *"...this job should be entrusted to **he or him?***

It's 'him,' so, the choice is 'whom.'

But again, as I said, many may favor both: who/whom in the given context.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence would work fine in off-the-cuff speech, but is a little awkward on the page because of the two prepositions coming together ("to for").

I would be likely to re-word it as:

> I know **who** should be entrusted **with** this job for smooth handling

or

> I know **who** to entrust **with** this job for smooth handling.

But if I wanted to retain the original wording, I would keep "who":

> I know **who** this job should be entrusted **to** for smooth handling.

It is true that according to the rules of prescriptive grammar, "whom" would be more correct, but this sounds excessively formal:

> I know **to whom** this job should be entrusted for smooth handling.

Of course, you could also re-word it as:

> I know **which employee** this job should be entrusted **to** for smooth handling.